# Matplotlib bar3d shadow issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to remove the dark shadow from bar3d plot?
I know for many other 3d plot options the `shade=False` can be used, but not bar3d.

I wanted to put some text on the top of some bars, but obviously being dark is very bad for display, it would be great if you can suggest me what may be done.

[image: example plot]

Comment: The docs explain how to change the colours of each face of the bars independently: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d

Comment: And the example here shows how to use the `shade=False` option: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html

Comment: Thanks for the links, however somehow I don't have the shade options, might be a version discrepancy?
AttributeError: Unknown property shade

Comment: Update to the latest version (2.2.0)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turns out I was stuck with 2.0.2. After upgrading it works now.